# Dealing with a mis-typed date in a vba array

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, date, runtime-error

I wrote some code that pulls data from a lotus notes database and writes it to a variant type array. My problem now is that I can't write that array to an excel range. I get an "application defined or object-defined error." I think I know why:

Someone mis-typed a date in the lotus notes database. Instead of typing "07/08/2011" they typed "07/08/0211." So one of the elements in the array contains "07/08/0211" stored as a date sub-type. When I try to write the array to a range, only part of the array is copied. I receive the error, and everything in the array after the typo is cut off.

I don't really care about correcting the date, I just need to find a way to ignore it and get the full contents of the array copied into the spreadsheet.

Thanks in advance for the help!

```
Sub DRupdate()

    Dim db As Object
    Dim doc As Object
    Dim session As New NotesSession
    Dim view As Object

    Dim row As Long
    Dim arr_1(1 To 2) As Variant
    Dim arr_2() As Variant
    Dim LastUpdated As String
    Dim EccLastRow As Range

    Dim item_values(50000, 4) As Variant
    Dim password As String
    Dim query As String
    Dim j As Long

    password = "xxxx"

    'intitialize lotus notes session using user-supplied password
    session.Initialize (password)

    'Set variable equal to date of last update stored on the "config" worksheet
    LastUpdated = config.Range("C5").Value


    'Acess ECC database, Emergency ECC view
    Set db = session.GetDatabase("xxxx", "xxxx")
    Set view = db.GetView("xxxx")

    row = 0

    'Create query to search for documents that have "YR" in apparatus field, and have a creation date on or after the last time the workbook was updated
    query = "[_CreationDate]>=" & LastUpdated

    j = view.FTSearch(query, 0)

    Set doc = view.GetFirstDocument

    'On Error GoTo Errhandler

    'Get item values of interest from database and write to the item_values array
    Do
        item_values(row, 0) = doc.GetItemValue("DftgReqNo_1")(0)
        item_values(row, 1) = doc.GetItemValue("TypeWorkReq")(0)
        item_values(row, 2) = doc.GetItemValue("OrigDate")(0)
        item_values(row, 3) = doc.GetItemValue("ReqCompDate")(0)

        If item_values(row, 2) <> "" And item_values(row, 3) <> "" Then

            item_values(row, 4) = DateDiff("d", item_values(row, 2), item_values(row, 3))
        Else
            item_values(row, 4) = "N/A"
        End If

        row = row + 1

        Set doc = view.GetNextDocument(doc)
    Loop While Not (doc Is Nothing)


    With DRdata

        'Append new data to end of ecc table
        .Range(.Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Offset(1, 0), .Range("A999999").End(xlUp).Offset(5000, 3)) = item_values

        'Delete any duplicates
        .Range("A1", .Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(0, 3)).RemoveDuplicates Columns:=Array(1), Header:=xlYes

     End With

    'Write date of last update onto "config" sheet
    config.Range("C5").Value = Date

Errhandler:

        Select Case Err

            Case 91:
                MsgBox ("Drafting Request data is up to date")

        End Select

End Sub
```

Comment: can you show some code?

Comment: I added code, but I think the only problem is when I write the array to the range in the "With DRdata" block.

Comment: DRdata is the vba code name of the worksheet. I'm convinced the problem lies with the mis-typed date in the array, because most of the array does get printed to the range. It just gets cut off when it encounters the typo.

Comment: but where have you defined it?

Comment: I just changed the codename property in the properties window http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa214189(v=office.11).aspx

Comment: Have you some data validation in the destination range?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/45752/discussion-between-danw-and-simoco)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by changing the code as follows:

```
 Do
    item_values(row, 0) = Cstr(doc.GetItemValue("DftgReqNo_1")(0))
    item_values(row, 1) = Cstr(doc.GetItemValue("TypeWorkReq")(0))
    item_values(row, 2) = Cstr(doc.GetItemValue("OrigDate")(0))
    item_values(row, 3) = Cstr(doc.GetItemValue("ReqCompDate")(0))

    If item_values(row, 2) <> "" And item_values(row, 3) <> "" Then

        item_values(row, 4) = Cstr(DateDiff("d", item_values(row, 2),item_values(row,3)))
    Else
        item_values(row, 4) = "N/A"
    End If

    row = row + 1

    Set doc = view.GetNextDocument(doc)
Loop While Not (doc Is Nothing)
```